# VB.2010 form not showing controls in the IDE

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a VB.2010 Windows Desktop App that has been running for years.

As of this morning there is 1 form out of dozens of forms the app has does not show any of the controls in designer mode and not even the correct size.  Look like a brand new form except the form does not any text (new form would be form1, etc.).   Yesterday there was no problem.

The designer module is there as is the resx module.

When looking at the Solution Explorer showing all files the modules appear but no indented under the vb module.  It is almost like VB is treating them as totally separate modules.

Went to a back of the source folder from 5 months ago and it has the same problem for the same form.

If I run the app the form does show all the controls but I am not able to see / change the controls in designer mode.

Every tried re-booting the machine.

Since the 5 month old backup has the same problem it is not something in the source. So restoring the source would not help.

Looked at another VB.2010 app that is very similar to the above that uses the 'same' forms but in a different folder and this program does NOT have the problem.

HELP!!

Comment: Look at that forms designer file.  If the controls are declared at the bottom then they are still there.  You may be able to recover it if it is something simple wrong like they are never added to the Forms.Controls collection or have an invalid location.

Answer (score 0):

All the controls where there.  I fixed it by removing and deleting the 'bad form'. Then doing an add existing items from a backup folder (actually created when the form was still bad).

So there is/was nothing wrong with the source and I have no idea what caused it, why backups didn't work on 2 PCs, etc. etc.

Don't know if it will stay fixed but I am ending the day (yesterday) on the above good :)

Filed in: X-Files